# C/C++ macros with parameters

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I'm in doubt about using ## and # inside C macros.
I've found codes like this:

```
 #define GET_INSTANCE_PROC_ADDR(inst, entrypoint)                               \
{                                                                          \
    demo->fp##entrypoint =                                                 \
        (PFN_vk##entrypoint)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(inst, "vk" #entrypoint); \
    if (demo->fp##entrypoint == NULL) {                                    \
        ERR_EXIT("vkGetInstanceProcAddr failed to find vk" #entrypoint,    \
                 "vkGetInstanceProcAddr Failure");                         \
    }                                                                      \
}
```

I was able to deduces that double ## means it will repeat text parameter, but I don't understand the following segment:

```
 "vk" #entrypoint
```

After the prefix, it has a space and single # instead of ##.

Comment: Did you have a look at the generated replacement text? What did you do to find out yourself?

Comment: I guess seeing the results of a macro is subject for another thread. I try gcc -E, at codeblocks, but it doesn't work. This is project about binding Java and Vulkan, and main tools and expertise is on Java and 3D. Also, there is no  similar question/answer  at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`##` is the pasting operator. It ensures that the compiler thinks that the left side and the right side are just one token. If you write `GET_INSTANCE_PROC_ADDR(foo, bar)`, then `demo->fp##entrypoint` becomes `demo->fpbar`.

`#` gets the contents of the macro argument as a string. If you write `GET_INSTANCE_PROC_ADDR(foo, bar)`, then `#entrypoint` is `"bar"`.

In C and C++, it's legal to put two string literals next to one another and the compiler will concatenate them: `"this" "is" "valid"` is the same as `"thisisvalid"`.

Comment: `##` pasts the actual value of any two arguments. It does not necessarily result in a single token.

Comment: @zneak - nice reply. It's strange that this sort of info is so hard to find and how people assume this is a sort of obvious thing.  It's not obvious, and it is hard to find ! Thanks!